# how to get columns of selected rows using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried with below code and getting alert of the column name but didn't get all columns of the multiple selected rows. Here is the sample code.

```
$('body').on('click', 'td', function() {
    var selectedRows= $(this).toggleClass('selected');        
    var holdNames = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").text();
    $("#holdNames").val(holdNames);

    var holdsArr = [];
    for ( var index=0; index<selectedRows.length;index++) {
        holdsArr.push(holdNames[index]);
    };
    alert(holdsArr);
 });
```

Comment: Can you please add an example of your HTML, and given that HTML, what you'd expect the code to return? Your question in its current form is not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will alert the 3rd `<td>` in each selected row
e.g. `Text1,Text2,Text3`

```
$('body').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var holdNames = $(this).children().eq(2).text();
    $("#holdNames").val(holdNames);

    var selectedRows= $('tr.selected');
    var holdsArr = [];
    for ( var index=0; index<selectedRows.length;index++) {
        var name = selectedRows.eq(index).children().eq(2).text();
        holdsArr.push(name);
    };
    alert(holdsArr);
});
```

A better approach would be

```
  var holdsArr = [];
$(document).on('click','tr',function(){
    var $tr = $(this);
    $tr.toggleClass('selected');
    updateHoldsArr();
    alert(holdsArr);
});

function updateHoldsArr(){
    var $trs = $('tr.selected'),
        arr = [];
    $trs.each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).children().eq(2));
    });
    holdsArr = arr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its helped me and solved my issue.